# RadioButton check programmatically

Tags: android

I have the following radigroup in the xml

```
<RadioGroup
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/radiogroup">
  </RadioGroup>
```

and I am checking the number of objects in my json and generate radiobuttons and add them in the radiogroup as follows.

```
private void createRadioButton(int nImages) {
  final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[nImages];
  for(int i=0; i<nImages; i++){
    rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
    rb[i].setId(i);
    radioGroup.addView(rb[i]);
  }
}
```

now I need to know how to know and check selected radio button ?

when I was hardcoded, the following was working,

```
 radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton0);
```

but now I am adding radio buttons programmatically, I do not know how to handle

```
 radioGroup.check(??);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select radio button at a particular position in radiogroup, you can use

```
radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(position).getId());
```

where position is the position of the radio button in radio group

Comment: how could I assign different color in `radiobutton` selected circle ?

Answer (score 1):

you set id of radiobutton as index of array in this part of code `rb[i].setId(i);`
you can use the following code  `radioGroup.check(i);`